# AddFontResource + SetCurrentConsoleFontEx are not changing a console font

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, console, window

I'm trying to change a console font to a custom one, but this specific code piece doesn't seem to acomplish anything, even though this is what I came up while trying to find a solution around the Internet. I tested just the SetCurrentConsoleFontEx with this custom font by installing and adding it to the console with regestry by hand, and it's been functioning properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Default font" << std::endl;
    system("pause");

    HANDLE m_stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    AddFontResourceEx(L"Iosevka.ttf", FR_PRIVATE, 0);
    SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
    ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
    cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
    cfie.dwFontSize.Y = 21;
    lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Iosevka");

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(m_stdOut, false, &cfie);
    std::cout << "Custom font" << std::endl;
    RemoveFontResource(L"Iosevka.ttf");

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The console window is owned by a system process, that's why a private font of your process won't be usable by the console window.

Comment: @zett42 Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `AddFontResourceEx()` with `FR_PRIVATE` flag, which means the font is available only to your process.

Unfortunately, the console window is not part of your process (`GetWindowThreadProcessId()` lies in this regard!). It is hosted by a system process ("csrss.exe" before Win 7, "conhost.exe" since then).

See: [Windows Command-Line: Inside the Windows Console](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/07/20/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/)

To make the font available to the console, you have to remove the `FR_PRIVATE` flag or install the font permanently.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get AddFontResourceEx() to work, even without FR_PRIVATE flag by switching to AddFontResource(), but that wasn't helpfull as well. I decided to stick with adding font to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont first, then everything works nicely.