# How can I use SetCurrentConsoleFontEx with fonts loaded by AddFontMemResourceEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

My main goal is to set the console font to [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-13.0.04/) using windows API functions. I can successfully do this by calling `AddFontResource` with the filename. I would rather use `AddFontMemResourceEx` because then I can load the font from a Resource.
I tested a variety of calls to load the font, and here are the results:

```
AddFontResource(filename); //works
AddFontResourceEx(filename, FR_PRIVATE, NULL); //does not work
AddFontResourceEx(filename, FR_NOT_ENUM, NULL); //works
AddFontMemResourceEx(valid_pointer, data_size, NULL, &font_count); //does not work
```

I tested these with two fonts, Unifont, and Fira Code (the only other font I could find that would display on the terminal).

I wrote this program to cut out possible issues with loading the font as a resource.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::string filename = "unifont-13.0.04.ttf";
    std::wstring fontname = L"Unifont";

    auto fileSize = std::filesystem::file_size(filename);
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::binary);

    char* data = new char[fileSize];
    in.read(data, fileSize);
    in.close();

    DWORD loadedFonts = 0;
    AddFontMemResourceEx(reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(data), fileSize, NULL, &loadedFonts);

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 16;
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, fontname.c_str());

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);

    std::wcout << "I found " << loadedFonts << " fonts.";
    std::wcin.ignore();

    delete[] data;
}
```

With unifont, `AddFontMemResourceEx` will set `loadedFonts` to two, indicating it did find and load two fonts, and did not fail.

Worth noting, the `HANDLE` returned by `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` is entirely useless for doing anything except calling `RemoveFontMemResourceEx`, which you don't even need to do in most cases because the fonts will be unloaded when the process ends.

Why does `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` work with `AddFontResource` but not with `AddFontMemResourceEx`?

Comment: This can't work, the console is owned by a different process (conhost.exe).

Comment: @HansPassant So the problem is that the font is loaded in my process, but `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` sends the font name to conhost.exe, which does not have that font loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex#remarks),

> This function allows an application to get a font that is embedded in
> a document or a webpage. A font that is added by `AddFontMemResourceEx`
> is always **private** to the process that made the call and is not
> enumerable.

For other content, please refer to [zett42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905630/11128312),

> You are calling AddFontResourceEx() with FR_PRIVATE flag, which means
> the font is available only to your process.
>
> Unfortunately, the console window is not part of your process
> (GetWindowThreadProcessId() lies in this regard!). It is hosted by a
> system process ("csrss.exe" before Win 7, "conhost.exe" since then).